# How can i get the field values from contact form 7 and pass it to redirect url?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, contact-form-7

I want to redirect the user to calendly.com after form submission with the values.

My Current Code is like this.

```
<div class="new-contact-form form-contact-box">
  <div class="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group -animated">
          <label>Work Email</label>
          [email* email id:user_email class:form-control class:required] </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group -animated">
          <label>First Name</label>
          [text* first_name id:first_name class:form-control] </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group -animated">
          <label>Last Name</label>
          [text* last_name id:last_name class:form-control] </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group -animated">
          <label>Organisation</label>
          [text* organization_name id:organization_name class:form-control] </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 wmt-3">
        <div class="form-group -animated">
          <label class="mt-01">Select Plan</label>
          [select* request_plan id:request_plan class:form-control class:form-control-lg class:mt-2 include_blank "Silver" "Gold" "Platinum"] </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 wmt-3  well">
        <div class="form-group -animated">
          <label class="mt-01">Size of the Organization</label>
          [select* community_size class:form-control class:form-control-lg class:mt-2 include_blank "My self only" "2-10 employees" "11-50 employees" "51-200 employees" "201-500 employees" "501-1,000 employees" "1,001-5,000 employees" "5,001-10,000 employees" "10,001+ employees"] </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 role wmt-3">
        <div class="form-group -animated">
          <label class="mt-01">Your Role</label>
          [select* role class:form-control class:question class:form-control-lg class:mt-2 include_blank "User" "Initiator" "Decision Maker"] </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group wmt-3">
          <label>Short Note</label>
          [textarea requirement class:textarea class:mt-3 class:form-control placeholder "Type your text here..."] </div>
        <div class="btn-cloud btn-bg "> [submit "REQUEST A DEMO"] </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        location = 'https://calendly.com/cloudsocial-support/csdemo/';
    }, false );

</script>
```

It should be redirected with values like the First Name & Email so it will be pre-populated on calendly.

Calandly's suggested URL is `https://calendly.com/cloudsocial-support/csdemo?Name="name"/`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, either using javascript (client-side) or using PHP (server-side).

Here is a solution using javascript,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $form = $("form.wpcf7-form");

  $('input[type=submit].wpcf7-submit', $form).on('click', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    //on form submit prevent the form fields from being cleared by the cf7 plugin.
    $(':input',$form).each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      switch(true){
        case $this.is(':checked'):
          $this.prop("defaultChecked", true);
          break;
        case $this.is('select'):
          var values = $this.val();
          if(!$.isArray(values)) values = [values];
          $('option', $this).each(function(){
            var $option = $(this);
            $option[0].defaultSelected= false;
            if(values.indexOf($option.val()) >= 0){
              $option[0].defaultSelected=true;
            }
          });
          break;
        default:
          $this.prop("defaultValue", $this.val());
          break;
      }
    });
  });
  $(document).on( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    var attrs="name="+$('#first_name').val()+" "+$('#last_name').val();
    //maybe add some more fields to your uri...
    location = "https://localhost/cf7/?"+encodeURI(attrs);
  });
});
```

what this script does is:
- it retains all the field values when the form is submitted.  CF7 plugin clears all fields when you submit a form.
- if the submission is successful it redirects to the page nd populated the URI attributes from the form fields.